Custom popup with arrow/caret
How to make a dialog that automatically blurs the background and has an arrow as a pointer? What components are used?

Can you give me a reference or instructions on how to create a custom dialog?  What components can I use to be able to create a custom dialog that works the same.

Look for PopUpWindow or any ToolTip library ...

Please remove the redundant last paragraph and provide the code you have so far.

this my code : https://pastebin.com/ESTn8zkc

I tried to make it using popupwindow and this is the result:
Result Custom Popup
My Home Fragment :
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val btnShowPopup = binding.showTooltip

    btnShowPopup.setOnClickListener {
        showTooltip(it)
    }
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

private fun showTooltip(anchorView: View) {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val tooltipView = TooltipLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), null, false)
    val arrowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tooltip_arrow, null, false)

    val container = LinearLayout(context)
    container.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    container.addView(tooltipView.root)
    container.addView(arrowView)

    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(container, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true)

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null)

    val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    layoutParams.copyFrom((requireActivity().window.attributes).apply {
        alpha = 0.5f
        dimAmount = 5.0f
    })

    requireActivity().window.attributes = layoutParams

    val location = IntArray(2)
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location)
    val anchorX = location[0]
    val anchorY = location[1]

    container.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    val tooltipHeight = container.measuredHeight
    val tooltipWidth = container.measuredWidth

    val xOffset = anchorX + (anchorView.width / 2) - (tooltipWidth / 2)
    val yOffset = anchorY - tooltipHeight

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xOffset, yOffset)

    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener {
        val defaultLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
        defaultLayoutParams.copyFrom(requireActivity().window.attributes)
        defaultLayoutParams.alpha = 1.0f
        defaultLayoutParams.dimAmount = 0.0f
        requireActivity().window.attributes = defaultLayoutParams
    }
}

}

It looks like you are still having problems, yet you’ve posted an answer. When you post an answer, it suggests you’ve solved your own problem and no longer need help from the community. To avoid that, you’ll want to delete this answer and edit your findings instead into your original question as additional things you’ve tried.
